# Coloring a picture of a sculpture realisticly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

I want to color a picture realisticly but, since i am quite new to photoshop, i have no clue how i cloud achive this.

The goal is to paint the given sculpture in a realistic way but only to a certain amount beginning at the tip of its trunk.

[[image: The picture in question1]

Comment: The realistic elephant image coloring filter is not especially common in graphics software. Today it's not at all sure it's non-existent. An artificial intelligence service may well succeed to do it by reusing images aivailable in the web. Your only DIY-option is to study existing elephant (or maybe marble statue)  images  and to practice painting in Photoshop. That's a big effort for a beginner, but surely useful.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you are using Photoshop, you'd just have to paint on top of the raster image.  Do you have expertise in painting or drawing?  Perhaps use reference photographs of real elephants to help you.

Comment: I think it would be easier for a beginner to find a photo of a *real* elephant and then smooth and remove color from the parts desired. Mimicking the glossy white is surely easier than mimicking a real elephant via painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going for true photo-realism or just 'more grey'?

You could actually just play with the curves, then dab a bit of pink in the ears. As you said 'starting from the trunk', I've faded out the elephant's rear half back to the original colour, using a mask…

[image]

There was actually a surprising amount of detail in the trunk texture once the contrast was increased, unfortunately, the picture quality was very blocky [jpg artefacts] so it wasn't worth posting anything more than a screenshot of the process. You'd really have to start from a higher quality original.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a curves adjustment layer to make the statue darker and to make some surface details visible. But keep the white background. That's essentially suggested already by others.

Fix the most disturbing glosses with a soft low opacity clone brush.

Insert a Hue/saturation adjustment layer in colorize mode to set the color which is real for you. An example:

[image]